# Get the top tracks of a spotify artist in javascript using spotify-web-api-js

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

I am makeing a website and I want to get the 4 toptracks of a specific spotify-artist. I am using [spotify-web-api-js](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js) to ineract with the api. Does anyone know how?
I have read the docs but only saw it listed in the list of what you can do but not how to implement it.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the .getArtistsTopTracks method of spotify-web-api-js.
For example:

```js
import Spotify from "spotify-web-api-js"
const spotify = new Spotify()

const artistId = [/* get spotify artist id */]
const countryId = [/* US for united states */] 
const options = { limit: 4 }

spotify.getArtistTopTracks(artistId, countryId, options)
  .then(res => {
    
  })
```

Comment: I tryed but now i get the responds "no token provided", but only on the getArtistTopTracks method...